# Каков механизм изменения значения переменных в цикле for Python

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, ссылки

Каким образом изменяется значение списков `forenames` и `surnames`, если мы явно не меняем их значения? Это связано с `names`, какую роль это играет во внешнем цикле и как добавляя в него элемент, мы меняем значения списков `forenames` и `surnames`?

```
def get_forenames_and_surnames():

    forenames = []  
    surnames = [] 

    for names, filename in ((forenames, "forenames.txt"),
                                 (surnames, "surnames.txt")):

        for name in open(filename, encoding='utf8'):
            names.append(name.rstrip())
    return forenames, surnames
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала пример:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.append(4)
print(a)
print(b)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Вопрос**: почему поменялись оба списка, когда меняли только список `a`?

**Ответ:**

В Python переменные являются ссылками (идентификаторами) на хранящиеся в памяти объекты, поэтому:

- `a = [1, 2, 3]` означает - создай объект типа **list**, заполни его значениями `1, 2, 3` и присвой ссылку на этот объект переменной `a`.
- `b = a` - присвой переменной `b` ссылку, которая хранится в переменной `a` (которая в свою очередь указывает на объект). Теперь две переменных указывают на один и тот же объект.
- `a.append(4)` - найди объект по ссылке в переменной `a` и добавь в него элемент `4`. Помним, что объект у нас один, на него указывают `a` и `b`. Если сделаем `b.append(4)`, результат будет такой же.

**Упрощённая схема связи переменных и объектов:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь разберём ваш код:

```
# Вспомогательная функция для печати идентификатора объекта
def print_object_id(var_name, obj):
    # Функция id возвращает идентификатор объекта.
    obj_id = id(obj)

    print('{:X} - "{:s}" id'.format(obj_id, var_name))


def get_forenames_and_surnames():

    print("===Назначение переменных===")
    forenames = []  
    # Печатаем, какой идентификатор присвоился переменной forenames
    print_object_id("forenames", forenames)

    surnames = []
    # Печатаем, какой идентификатор присвоился переменной surnames
    print_object_id("surnames", surnames)

    print("\n===Внешний цикл for===")
    for names, filename in ((forenames, "forenames.txt"), (surnames, "surnames.txt")):
        ### На каждой итерации переменной "names" присваивается новый идентификатор:
        # В первой итерации это идентификатор переменной forenames 
        # Вo второй итерации это идентификатор переменной surnames 
        print_object_id("names", names)

        for name in open(filename, encoding='utf8'):
            # По идентификатору хранящемся в "names", Python ищет у
            # себя объект (в нашем случае это объект типа List)
            # и вызывает у этого объекта метод "append".
            # В итоге, новой элемент добавляется к списку.
            names.append(name.rstrip())

    return forenames, surnames

get_forenames_and_surnames()
```

**Output**

```
===Назначение переменных===
7F552E85B388 - "forenames" id
7F552E85B3C8 - "surnames" id

===Внешний цикл for===
7F552E85B388 - "names" id ### Тот же самый, что и у forenames
7F552E85B3C8 - "names" id ### Тот же самый, что и у surnames
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Никогда не получал такого глубокого ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее сложной является команда

```
for names, filename in ((forenames, "forenames.txt"),
                             (surnames, "surnames.txt")):
```

То, что за `in`, есть *кортеж из 2 элементов:*

- `(forenames, "forenames.txt")`  (первый элемент)
- `(surnames, "surnames.txt")`  (второй элемент)

Значит, тело цикла будет повторяться *только дважды:*

- первый раз для `names == forenames` и `filename == "forenames.txt"`
- второй раз для `names == surnames`  и `filename == "surnames.txt"`

В каждой из этих итераций выполнится тело цикла:

```
    for name in open(filename, encoding='utf8'):
        names.append(name.rstrip())
```

Значит, в первой итерации откроется файл `forenames.txt` и строки из него добавятся к списку `forenames`, в другой то же самое с файлом `surnames.txt` и списком `surnames`.