# Обращение к переменной по ссылке в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, указатели, ссылка

Сегодня буду краток. Есть код:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
arr = [a, b, c]
for i in range(3):
    arr[i] += 1

print(a, b, c)  # output: 1 2 3
```

А мне нужно `output: 2 3 4`. Как можно, изменяя элементы в списке, изменить элементы, которые были добавлены изначально? Что-то вроде ссылки и указателя?

UPD: я значительно упростил код, поэтому дам некоторые уточнения: так называемые переменные `a`, `b` и `c` являются атрибутами класса, и я сомневаюсь, что можно решить проблему через `globals()`

Comment: восстановите после цикла `a,b,c = arr`

Comment: splash58, да это же гениально! Я серьезно, ваше решение определенно подходит мне

Comment: @МихаилМуратов Ну и отлично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение `arr[i] += 1` соответствует: `arr[i] = arr[i] + 1` что переписывает ссылку, на новую (с новым значением), поэтому ваш код и не работает.

Вообще `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3` означает, что переменные `a, b, c` хранят ссылки на объекты `1, 2, 3`. А тут `arr = [a, b, c]` вы не ссылки на переменные положили, а сами ссылки на объекты `1, 2, 3`.

Вам проще к самим переменным обратиться и поменять значением, чем так. Либо оставить значения в словаре или в списке и работать с ними.

Но если очень хочется, можно рефлексией поменять у переменных:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
arr = [a, b, c]
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    globals()[i] += 1

print(a, b, c)  # 2 3 4
```

---

> и я сомневаюсь, что можно решить проблему через globals()

Через `globals()` и вправду не получится, т.к. оно меняет глобальные переменные, а вот для изменения в объектах использовать `getattr` и `setattr`:

```
class Foo:
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

foo = Foo()
arr = [foo.a, foo.b, foo.c]

for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    x = getattr(foo, i)
    setattr(foo, i, x + 1)

print(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)  # 2 3 4
```

Comment: Я добавил уточнения в вопрос

Comment: @МихаилМуратов, `a,b,c = arr` это вариант :) Обновил ответ :)

Comment: О, это тоже полезно, надо будет запомнить

Answer (score 4):

Kогда мне нужно обеспечить изменение объекта "по ссылке", я применяю такой способ:

```
a, b, c = [1], [2], [3] 
arr = [a, b, c]
for i in range(3):
    arr[i][0] += 1

print(a[0], b[0], c[0])  # output: 2 3 4
```

#### Объяснение.

**Немного общей теории:**

**Объекты числового типа неизменяемы**, к такому объекту нельзя прибавить единицу, можно только создать новый числовой объект с нужным значением и заменить на него исходный. Соответственно:

- `а = 1` означает: создай объект со значением `1` и помести его в глобальный словарь с переменными (`globals`) под именем `a`.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- `а = a + 1` означает: найди в словаре с переменными объект под именем `a`, сложи его с объектом `1`, результат запиши в новый объект `2`. В глобальном словаре замени значение `a` ссылкой на этот объект.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3` - создай три числовых объекта, запиши их ссылки в словарь с переменными под именами `a, b, c`, соответственно. Тут ещё задействованы кортежи, но про них не буду говорить, чтобы не усложнять.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Объекты типа list изменяемы**, в список можно добавлять и удалять значения, можно менять уже находящиеся в списке. Список хранит не сами объекты, **а ссылки на них**, меняя значение в списке, мы на самом деле заменяем ссылку предыдущего объекта на новую, указывающую на другой объект.

- `arr = [a, b, c]` - создай объект типа **список** и наполни его ссылками на объекты, которые хранятся в словаре с переменными под именами `a, b, c`. Какая ссылка хранится под именем `a`? Ссылка на числовой объект `1`. Под именем `b` ссылка на `2` и т. д.  Таким образом, имеем `arr = [1, 2, 3]` - список `arr` не хранит ни самих переменных, ни информации из каких переменных объекты `1, 2, 3` были получены. **Кстати,** теперь каждый из трёх объектов `1, 2, 3` имеет на себя как минимум по две ссылки - одна в глобальном словаре с переменными (`a`, `b`, `c`), другая внутри списка `arr`.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Когда вы делаете `arr[0] += 1`, вы берёте из списка нулевой элемент, который представляет из себя ссылку на числовой объект `1` и прибавляете к этому объекту единицу. Информации про переменную, с помощью которой вы этот объект назначали, в списке нет. Результат (ссылку на новый объект) записываете обратно в нулевой элемент списка.

**Использование списка для сохраненения ссылки на значение переменной:**

- `a, b, c = [1], [2], [3]` - оборачиваем каждый числовой объект в список и пишем **ссылку на этот список** в переменную. Помним, что объект типа список хранит не сам числовой объект, а ссылку на него. Следовательно, под именем `a` у нас хранится ссылка на список, который содержит единственный элемент - ссылку на объект `1`.
- `arr = [a, b, c]` - эту строчку можно представить как `arr = [[1], [2], [3]]`. Информацию о переменных `a`, `b`, `c` мы потеряли также, как и в предыдущем случае, однако сейчас и переменная `a`, и `arr[0]` указывают на список `[1]`. И этот список содержит нужное нам значение, которое мы можем менять, сохраняя в `a` и `arr[0]` ссылку на список-обёртку.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- `arr[0][0] += 1` - возьми нулевой элемент из списка. В нашем случае это `[1]`. Возьми и у него нулевой элемент. Это будет числовой объект `1`. Прибавь к нему единицу. Получившимся новым объектом замени нулевой элемент в списке `[1]`. Список мы не трогаем, а лишь меняем внутри него элемент на другой. Ссылка на список остаётся неизменной, переменная `a` продолжает на него указывать, только теперь этот список содержит `2` вместо `1`.

---

1. [Мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/939584/325224) на похожую тему.
2. В мануале на английском этот способ под № 3: [How do I write a function with output parameters (call by reference)?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference).

Comment: Это очень простое и удобное решение, правда немного загромождает код. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

arr = [a, b, c]

a, b, c = map(lambda x: x+1, arr)

print(a, b, c)
```

---

```
2 3 4
```

Comment: Это хорошее решение, но не во всех случаях может быть полезно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
arr = [a, b, c]
for i in range(3):
    arr[i] += 1

print(*arr)  # output: 2 3 4
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]