# Передать переменную по ссылке

Tags: python, python-3.x

В питоне некоторые объекты передаются по ссылке, а другие -- по значению. Есть ли возможность передать объект по ссылке принудительно?

```
def my_func(x):
   print(x) 
   x = 5
   print(x)


y = 5
print(y)
my_func(y)
print(y)
```

Можно ли передать `y` по ссылке принудительно?

Comment: Переменную нельзя передать. Передается всегда значение и всегда по ссылке.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да, ровно так я и сделал. Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1037175/325224. С теорией.